# How can I make a good looking candle flame effect to be used in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: lighting, effects

I want to have a candle effect I can use in Unreal Engine 4 that I can stick onto this candle mesh I've made.

What would the best way to do it be?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

what @haarigertroll suggested is doable, also given that your art style is low-poly you could use a super low-res mesh as the flame body. And then just use a noise texture or something to do vertex displacement in UE.

I did this in blender but it would be virtually identical in Unreal.

[low-poly candle animated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvTBo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As it seems to be an asset with little significance for details, I'd suggest using a textured plane set as billboard (i.e. always facing the camera).
You can either draw the texture with a few frames of animation or animate the top vertices of the plane, so you get a little bit of flicker. Don't forget to use transparency with your texture.

Obviously, the texture should be set for "emission".